# How can I set the camera to default to HDR on?

Tags: iphone, camera, hdr

I'd like to set my (iOS7) iPhone's camera to always default to HDR **on**. I do enable HDR when I'm taking pictures, but it always seems like the iPhone forgets the setting and goes back to HDR off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the "Flash" settings you select:

- Flash-Auto : HDR - Auto
- Flash-Off : HDR - On
- Flash-On : HDR - OFF

*So, whenever you force the Flash ON, HDR reverts to OFF. Alternatively, turning Flash OFF retains the HDR ON setting*

Answer (score 0):

On a stock (non-jailbroken) iPhone running iOS 7, this appears to not be possible (see for example https://discussions.apple.com/message/23530580#23530580#23530580). Yes, turning on the flash will automatically disable HDR, but even if the flash is left off the camera will eventually revert to non-HDR mode.